# Register custom Transformation in SSIS Toolbox

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012-datatools

In VS 2010, how would you register/add a custom transformation to the toolbox?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by custom transformation, but if you want to import a custom task, try importing your .dll to assembly folder in c:\windows, start vs and rightclick the toolbar -> choose items.

Answer (score 0):

Add the *.dll file of your customized component in the default Toolbar folder under the SSIS installation and then right click on the toolbar in the SSIS project window.

Then you will have to choose items and select the *.dll that was pasted in the folder.

http://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/steps-to-build-and-deploy-custom-ssis-components/

This link may help with the screenshot

Kindly let know if it is useful